# Cordova and google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

Well im trying to make simple app which will display map and user location i did everything like in this tutorial http://kendrickcoleman.com/index.php/Tech-Blog/phonegap-cordova-geolocation-integration-with-google-maps-javascript-api-v3.html
I have downloaded `cordova.js` from github i have correct key and all i can see on my avd is grey-white screen without any map, coudl someone give me a clue what shoudl i change ?

shoudl i add anything to android manifest or to config file ?

Comment: Follow this link tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037702/how-do-you-display-map-google-on-a-phonegap-android-application/26038477#26038477

Comment: This is the good example for Hybrid Application developer http://jsfiddle.net/vsah/284vt4wu/1/

Comment: nice to share your code to see anything you missed out?

Comment: you don't have to download cordova.js from github, you have to install cordova, create a cordova project, and it generates a different cordova.js for every platform you add

Comment: if you are working with cordova I recommend this plugin : https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin It uses the Android and iOS Google Maps SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Battled with the same issue for 3 days only to discover that http request are blocked in the latest Ionic except a the cordova whitelist plugin is added.
To add whitelist plugin, run the following command:
 **ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist**