# phonegap geolocation does not work

Tags: cordova, geolocation

Hello the geolocation from phonegap doesn't work for me. here is my code.

```
function getGeo() {
    alert("begin getGeo");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

function onSuccess(position) {
    alert("onsuccess");
    var test = '"lat":"' + (position.coords.latitude) + '", "long":"' + (
        position.coords.longitude);
    alert(test);
}

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'messagee: ' + error.message +
        '\n');
}
```

i get an alert "begin getGeo" and than nothing happens.

in my config.xml file i added this line.

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.10" />
```

Comment: First on Location services from setting in your device, try this link it may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037702/how-do-you-display-map-google-on-a-phonegap-android-application/26038477#26038477

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {maximumAge:600000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy: true});

function onSuccess(position) {
    //Lat long will be fetched and stored in session variables
    //These variables will be used while storing data in local database 
    localStorage.setItem("lat", position.coords.latitude);
    localStorage.setItem("long", position.coords.longitude);
}
function onError(error) {
    if (error.code == error.TIMEOUT)
    {
        // Attempt to get GPS loc timed out after 5 seconds, 
        // try low accuracy location
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
               onSuccess, 
               errorCallback_lowAccuracy,
               {maximumAge:600000, timeout:10000, enableHighAccuracy: false});
        return;
    }
    alert("GeoLocation didn't worked, try to reboot your internet connection or your device, the app will close now.");
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}

function errorCallback_lowAccuracy(error) {
    alert("GeoLocation didn't worked, try to reboot your internet connection or your device, the app will close now.");
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

Comment: i tested it and i get the alert from the function "errorCallback_lowAccuracy" mmh

Comment: try to rebbot your device

Comment: i do. but still the same alert.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot insert this file before the code.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/www/geolocation.js

`getCurrentPosition:function(successCallback, errorCallback, options)` function inside this file.