# PhoneGap and map

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova

I have problem with map which deploy on **phoneGap**. 
After I read many tutorial about PhoneGap I succeed to install this cross platform tool, but I can not use **map** **on the PhoneGap**. I read some example about use map on the PhoneGap via js but none of them donot work for me!
I want to install my application on Android platform.

Do you have any hint or example regards to PhoneGap and map?

Comment: See this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037702/how-do-you-display-map-google-on-a-phonegap-android-application/26038477#26038477

Comment: Thanks, I see that, but I need to show location and route in streets.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what behavior you expect from map plugin/library. For me, this [jQuery map library](https://github.com/wimagguc/jquery-latitude-longitude-picker-gmaps) works the same way as on the web. It offers  location picking with the marker, searching, displaying location based on the gps or location name.