# Geolocation using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, plugins, build, geolocation, config

I am trying to get geolocation working in PhoneGap but cannot as of yet.

I am not wanting to use the command line, just edit the config file, if possible.

I have added:

```
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.10" />
```

as well as...

```
 <feature name="Geolocation">
 <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
 </feature>
```

I am trying to get their example working in the docs, a simple alert giving location details that they give in the documentation, to check it works before adding my own code.

Thanks.

Comment: and im using PhoneGap Build version 3.6.3

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037702/how-do-you-display-map-google-on-a-phonegap-android-application/26038477#26038477