# jquery mobile/cordova google maps issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, cordova, jquery-mobile

I' trying to create a simple map on a jquery mobile app page.

The problem is that I am getting a gray map.

**HTML:**

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div data-role="page" id="map-page" data-url="map-page">
   <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
    <center><img src="img/logo.png" style="height: 32px;"></center>
        <a data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="back" data-icon-pos="right" class="ui-alt-icon" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map-canvas">

    </div>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
var map; // Global so can be called anywhere
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    var mapOptions = {
        //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 7
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
})

function setMarker(lat,lng,info) {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat + ',' + lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      title: info
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
 }

$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $(document).on("click", "li", function (e) {
       setMarker(1,2,"test");
     })
 })
```

I cannot understand the reason for this.

Comment: It's a little different to use maps on cordova. Follow this: [**Link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037702/how-do-you-display-map-google-on-a-phonegap-android-application/26038477#26038477)