# Google map is not showing in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, phonegap-plugins

I am making an app in Phonegap in which i have to show a Google map. I have followed the tutorial https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Phonegap-Usage

But it is displaying the error:

```
cordova.js plugins/plugins-google.maps/www/googlemap-cdv-plugin is undefined.
```

Please tell me how i can resolve this error.

Comment: try `cordova remove plugin.google.maps and cordova add plugin.google.maps` again couple of times.

Comment: i have already done this but issue still persist

Comment: @shivani Google map plugins are too complex to use with cordova application. You can use Javascript Google map this is better option to use Google map feature in your app.

Comment: Check this link it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037702/how-do-you-display-map-google-on-a-phonegap-android-application/26038477#26038477

Comment: @shivani have you tried this `C:\test\HelloMap> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_API_KEY_IS_HERE"`

Comment: Hi , I have used javascript without plugin and that is working ok .Now i want to draw path(polyline) on map between one location to another .Can you please guide me further? Thanks all of you for help

Comment: try this [examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple)

Comment: Ok i will try it .BTW i have one more question please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566214/javascript-or-jquery-is-not-working-in-ios-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

Please check your project with one of [this](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/TroubleShooting:-Blank-Map) issue. Make sure you use the latest one.